# Reshaping to long with multiple values columns

Tags: r

I know there are several "duplicate" threads on this issue, but I've looked at them and can't figure out how to get `reshape` to do what I want.

I have a dataset where participants take two tests, each with two questions (i.e., Question 1 Test 1, Question 2 Test 1, Question 1 Test 2, Question 2 Test 2). They can either get the question `right` or `wrong`. I've changed the Test 1 answers to `0` and `1` so it's easier to see the issue.

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "

subj Q1.test1 Q2.test1 Q1.test2 Q2.test2
 1        0        1    right    wrong
 2        0        1    wrong    wrong

")
```

I would like to reshape this to long so that it looks like this:

```
subj question test1 test2
 1       Q1     0   right
 2       Q1     0   wrong
 1       Q2     1   wrong
 2       Q2     1   wrong
```

However, whenever I try to reshape it, it does not result in the dataframe I want.

```
df.long <- reshape(df, direction = "long",
                    varying = c("Q1.test1", "Q2.test1", "Q1.test2", "Q2.test2"),
                    timevar = "question",
                    times = c("Q1", "Q2"),
                    v.names = c("test1", "test2"),
                    idvar = "subj")

df.long

subj question test1 test2
  1       Q1     0     1
  2       Q1     0     1
  1       Q2 right wrong
  2       Q2 wrong wrong
```

The problem is of course the arguments that I'm using in `reshape`; Is it possible to do what I'm looking for using `reshape`, or should I look into a different package?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it using the `tidyr` package. Note: use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the data frame or there will be warnings. I call the data frame `df1`.

`gather` converts from wide to long, `separate` splits the column names into new columns and `spread` creates the columns with values for each test.

[A useful tutorial](http://www.milanor.net/blog/reshape-data-r-tidyr-vs-reshape2/) comparing `tidyr` and `reshape`.

```
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -subj) %>% 
  separate(Var, sep = "\\.", into = c("question", "test")) %>% 
  spread(test, Val)
```

Result:

```
  subj question test1 test2
1    1       Q1     0 right
2    1       Q2     1 wrong
3    2       Q1     0 wrong
4    2       Q2     1 wrong
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                  text = "subj Q1.test1 Q2.test1 Q1.test2 Q2.test2
 1        0        1    right    wrong
 2        0        1    wrong    wrong", 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```